# Accepting payment in multiple currency using paypal

Tags: php, paypal, authorize.net

Currently we accept payment in dollars on our website, we are using paypal and auth.net as payment gateway. Now we want our users to make payment in both currencies dollar as well as euro.

How can i do that, Our web application is developed in cs-cart.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to call PayPal customer Service to have this set up for you. Once the account is set up you can simply pass the corresponding currency code in your API call, something to the effect of `currency_code=USD`. For more information, see [Currencies and Currency Codes Supported by PayPal](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_websitepaymentsstandard_integrationguide.pdf) .